# Cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm stuck with the below line showing the error: "cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer".

```
for i in range(len(rebalance_dates)):
    new_table.ix[rebalance_dates[i]:rebalance_dates[i+1]] = np.round((final_data.ix[rebalance_dates[i]), 0)
```

There are two tables, `new_table` and `final_data`, using their index as datetime like '2016-01-01'. I guess the error occurs when looping datetime index.

The error doesn't appear when I delete the for loop statement and change it to

```
 new_table.ix[rebalance_dates[0]] = np.round((final_data.ix[rebalance_dates[0]),0)
```

Wonder how I can fix this problem to run a loop statement with datetime index. Thanks.

Comment: you don't need a loop for this. use `Dataframe.rolling`. As for your dtype issue, we need to see your data within a reproducible example

Comment: @PaulH the question was asked almost six years ago, and attracted no other comments or answers. It seems unlikely that a MRE is forthcoming... it's also unclear to me why the question got upvotes.

Comment: Probably because it's one of the first results when you search for "cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer". To me, it was helpful in so far, as that I realized that the error probably has to do with my (datetime) index and not the data itself. Maybe that's the first step to fixing it.